# Observer Pattern on MVC for specific fields

Tags: java, model-view-controller, listener, observer-pattern

On the MVC pattern, which is the best option for the Model to notify the View (if this is the right approach in the first place) where, from all the fields of data the Model is storing, only a couple of them are updated. Specifically when we only want to update specific fields of the View.

I am currently using a MVC pattern with Observer/Subscriber (JAVA Swing) as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963529 but when the Model updates, it changes everything in the View when the `update()` funcion is called,  it's impossible to determine which field from the Model changed in order to update only the required field in the View.

I read this topic: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/359008 and this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815189 which I think it's usefull, but for the later, I can't understand very well how can I set a propertyChangeListener on a variale (int, float, etc). Also related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815189

The Main class where the software start to run:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model m = new Model();
        View v = new View(m);
        Controller c = new Controller(m, v);
        c.initController();
    }
}
```

So the code that I have on Model is this:

```
public class Model extends Observable {
   //...
   private float speed;
   private int batteryPercentage;

   public float getSpeed() {
       return speed;
   }
   public void setSpeed(float speed) {
       this.speed = speed;
       setChanged();
       notifyObservers();
   }

    public int getBatteryPercentage() {
        return batteryPercentage;
    }
    public void setBatteryPercentage(int batteryPercentage) {
        this.batteryPercentage = batteryPercentage;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

The view knows the Model:

```
public class View implements Observer {
    private Model model;
    private JTextField txtFldSpeed;
    private JTextField txtFldBattery;
    private JFrame mainWindow;

    public View(Model m) {
        this.model = m;
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setTitle("New Window");
        mainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        mainWindow.setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 720);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel tPanel1 = new JPanel();
        tPanel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        tPanel1.setLayout(null);
        mainWindow.getContentPane().add(tPanel1);

        mainWindow.getContentPane().add(tPanel1);
        txtFldSpeed = new JTextField();
        txtFldSpeed.setEditable(false);
        txtFldSpeed.setBounds(182, 11, 116, 22);
        tPanel1.add(txtFldSpeed);

        txtFldBattery = new JTextField();
        txtFldBattery.setEditable(false);
        txtFldBattery.setBounds(182, 43, 116, 22);
        tPanel1.add(txtFldBattery);

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        txtFldSpeed.setText(Float.toString(model.getSpeed()) + " kn");
        txtFldBattery.setText(Integer.toString(model.getBatteryPercentage()) + " %");
    }
}
```

The Controller adds the View as a Observer of the Model:

```
public class Controller {
    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public Controller(Model m, View v) {
        this.model = m;
        this.view = v;
    }

    public void initController() {    
        model.addObserver(view);
        model.setSpeed(10);
    }
}
```

What I am expecting is something that, when the Model is updated, let's say, function `setSpeed()` is called, the View is told that she needs to update itself on that specific field and not every "changable" field (like the `txtFldBattery`.

I want to do this because on the View, there are fields being updated a couple of times per second, and because I need to update everything on the view, a `JComboBox` which doesn't need to update that often, keeps closing when trying to select a option.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Also the more specific the question, and the better the [mcve] code you post, usually the higher quality the question is and the better the answer. Side note: usually the view has listeners added to the model that are fired when the model change. You can use one listener and simply update the entire view on model change, or you can use multiple listeners, and update things more selectively, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do. The details on any solution will depend on the details of your code and your problem.

Comment: Thanks for you help @HovercraftFullOfEels. I will updated with some code. I didn't think it would be usefull.

Comment: I don't think that I've been called "Ho" before, but I have been called worse (seriously). Again though, please improve your question if possible.

Comment: Not your down-voter (yet), awaiting your update

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, sorry! :-D I was trying to reference you. I updated the post. I omitted some code to make it easier to read as the variables are pretty straightforward as naming. Thank you.

Comment: Please read or re-read the [mcve] link to see the code that you should be posting. If you don't have an answer soon, then please feel free to comment back to me once you've posted code that conforms to the MCVE standards, including that it must be small (fits in your question unmodified), can be copied and pasted into our IDE's and then compiles and runs for us. The link will explain the details and why these details are important.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, done. I tried to clean the code and make it simple and compilable as best as I could. I think it shows what I am trying to accomplish clearly.

Comment: Thank you for the update but it still won't compile due to missing symbols: `messages` parameter to model constructor call, `gbc_tPanel1` field in method call, and Model method `getBatteryPercentage()` called within the update method. Again the code should compile for us out of the box and without our having to modify it. Best would be to have one file, the Main.java file, with one public Main class, and have the other classes be default access modifier and within the Main.java file (but not nested in the class itself.

Comment: Also, no Model constructor is defined and yet you call one that takes an unknown messages parameter.

Comment: Also, your code does nothing of use, does not create a JFrame/GUI, does not show or reproduce a problem for us, ...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oops. I missed some instructions. Now it compiles, at least on my side. It does create a JFrame. It's hard to reproduce a problem without putting out a lot of code. But I honestly think that the idea is there, you have a controller, which changes one field, and the objective is that the view, instead of updating all the fields, updates only the field that has been changed. Let me know what I can do to make the answer better. Thank you.

Comment: I would use SwingPropertyChangeSupport, make each of the model's state fields a "bound property" so that each state field can be listened to separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use SwingPropertyChangeSupport, make each of the model's state fields a "bound property" so that each state field can be listened to separately.

For instance, say you have a model that looked like this:

```
public class MvcModel {
    public static final String SPEED = "speed";
    public static final String BATTERY = "battery";
    public static final int MAX_SPEED = 40;
    private float speed;
    private int batteryPercentage;
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(float speed) {
        float oldValue = this.speed;
        float newValue = speed;
        this.speed = speed;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(SPEED, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public int getBatteryPercentage() {
        return batteryPercentage;
    }

    public void setBatteryPercentage(int batteryPercentage) {
        int oldValue = this.batteryPercentage;
        int newValue = batteryPercentage;
        this.batteryPercentage = batteryPercentage;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(BATTERY, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

}
```

Both the speed and the batteryPercent fields are "bound fields" in that any changes to these fields will trigger the property change support object to fire a notification message to any listeners that have registered with the support object, as reflected in the `public void setXxxx(...)` methods.

This way the controller could register listeners on the model for whatever properties it wants to listen to, and then notify the view of any changes. For example:

```
class SpeedListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        float speed = model.getSpeed();
        view.setSpeed(speed);
    }
}
```

The set up could look something like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class MVC2 {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MvcModel model = new MvcModel();
        MvcView view = new MvcView();
        MvcController controller = new MvcController(model, view);
        controller.init();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MVC2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(view.getMainDisplay());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class MvcView {
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JSlider speedSlider = new JSlider(0, MvcModel.MAX_SPEED);
    private JSlider batterySlider = new JSlider(0, 100);
    private JProgressBar speedBar = new JProgressBar(0, MvcModel.MAX_SPEED);
    private JProgressBar batteryPercentBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

    public MvcView() {
        speedSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        speedSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        speedSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        speedSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        speedSlider.setPaintTrack(true);

        batterySlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        batterySlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        batterySlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        batterySlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        batterySlider.setPaintTrack(true);

        speedBar.setStringPainted(true);
        batteryPercentBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        inputPanel.add(createTitledPanel("Speed", speedSlider));
        inputPanel.add(createTitledPanel("Battery %", batterySlider));

        JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        displayPanel.add(createTitledPanel("Speed", speedBar));
        displayPanel.add(createTitledPanel("Battery %", batteryPercentBar));

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        mainPanel.add(createTitledPanel("Input", inputPanel));
        mainPanel.add(createTitledPanel("Display", displayPanel));
    }

    private JComponent createTitledPanel(String title, JComponent component) {
        JPanel titledPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        titledPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        titledPanel.add(component);
        return titledPanel;
    }


    public JComponent getMainDisplay() {
        return mainPanel;
    }


    public void setSpeed(float speed) {
        speedBar.setValue((int) speed);
    }


    public void setBatteryPercent(int batteryPercent) {
        batteryPercentBar.setValue(batteryPercent);
    }


    public JSlider getSpeedSlider() {
        return speedSlider;
    }

    public JSlider getBatterySlider() {
        return batterySlider;
    }

}
```

```
class MvcController {
    private MvcModel model;
    private MvcView view;

    public MvcController(MvcModel model, MvcView view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        model.addPropertyChangeListener(MvcModel.BATTERY, new BatteryListener());
        model.addPropertyChangeListener(MvcModel.SPEED, new SpeedListener());

        view.getSpeedSlider().addChangeListener(chngEvent -> {
            int value = view.getSpeedSlider().getValue();
            model.setSpeed(value);
        });

        view.getBatterySlider().addChangeListener(chngEvent -> {
            int value = view.getBatterySlider().getValue();
            model.setBatteryPercentage(value);
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        view.getSpeedSlider().setValue(10);
        view.getBatterySlider().setValue(100);

        model.setSpeed(10);
        model.setBatteryPercentage(100);
    }

    class SpeedListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            float speed = model.getSpeed();
            view.setSpeed(speed);
        }
    }

    class BatteryListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            int batteryPercent = model.getBatteryPercentage();
            view.setBatteryPercent(batteryPercent);
        }
    }    
}
```

---

Side note: Observer and Observable have been deprecated in the most recent version of Java and so should their use should probably be avoided.

Comment: Hi! This is actually quite close what I figured it out later. I will look in detail at your answer, test it, and get back to you ASAP. I will also update the post accordingly.

Upvoted ;-) Thank you!

Comment: Hi again! I accepted this answer. Just one question, although I understand the difference between SwingPropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeSupport, why or when should I use the first one?

Comment: @Fred: the SwingPropertyChangeSupport is guaranteed to fire notifications on the Event Dispatch Thread and only on this thread, and so should be used for Swing GUI notifications. Note that all Swing components already hold one of these objects as a field of the class.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice Easter (if you celebrate it)!

Answer (score 1):

In your `update` method implementation you can determine with first argument `o` which Observable has changed and with second argument `arg` which value changed when you call: `notifyObservers(this.speed);`

Note that *notifyObservers*'s signature accepts `Object`, and `float` primitive is not a subclass of `Object`.

Comment: Hi @Sal. In my implementation I only have one Observable so that first argument is not needed. But about the second argument, I did not fully understand, so I know float is not a subclass of Object, but in that case it's not usefull because it doesn't actually tell you which field/value has been change but it's Class/Instance (?) if applicable. One possible solution would be to have a Object that has an attribute String which is defined before each notifyObservers call and passes that Object into the Observer which read the String and identifies the field. But is seems hardcoded as hell.

Comment: Just use equality operator `==`, it compares object references. `if(this.model.speed == arg)`

Comment: well thought! I will look into this and update you ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, giving the fact that the Observer pattern is being deprecated in Java 9, although I thank you for your help, I will investigate further the answer from @Hovercraft Full of Eels. You have my upvote! :-)